# Magento: Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Categorygroup_Helper_Data' not found in /app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: php, ce-1.8.1.0

im new in magento. i got this error in Magento backend right after reindexing and clearing the cache:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Categorygroup_Helper_Data' not found in /app/Mage.php on line 547
```

my backend is not working. what should i do?

Comment: From what I can tell **Mage_Categorygroup_Helper_Data** doesn't exist in core Magento. Have you installed any custom modules? Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: yes this happened right after reindexing and clearing the cache @Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happend (I can only guess) you installed/implemented a new module where the helper node in `config.xml` (`/config/global/helpers/<your_module_name>/class`) is missing.

The fallback of magento is to try mage_/.

And then this error is thrown.

It only happend after cleaning the cache, because the old config (without the module loaded) was cached and used.